# what could be the various ways to show crucial text on the website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-experience

I want to show a Critical text on the website, where I want the customer's attention.
What could be the various ways by which we can gain the customer focus on this text? we do not want that customer should miss reading this text.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the suggestion to you to use css like this to (color combination is choose dependents on your color theme).

I have edited answer with the beautiful examples for the highlight text [Example Demos](https://freebiesupply.com/blog/css-text-effects-from-codepen/)

```css
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme&display=swap');

body {
  background-color: #07020C;
  font-family: 'Acme', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  animation: shine 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes shine {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80% {
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff,
                   0 0 20px #fff,
                   0 0 40px #fff,
                   0 0 60px #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <span>H</span>
    <span>i</span>
    <span>g</span>
    <span>h</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>i</span>
    <span>g</span>
    <span>h</span>
    <span>t</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aaha! this is nice. I can modify the CSS.
Can you suggest any other option?

Comment: Yes , sure i will suggest.

Comment: I have edited my answer with the awesome link.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of user experience you can design a popup with a confirmation button.

the important thing in this confirmation button is that it should have a message that forces the person to read the content of the popup, like "I agree with that".

If you don't want to use a popup, you should try to display a message close to the object the user is interacting.

Comment: that's what I don't want. PopUp!
I don't want to hold the behavior of the user or restrict his actions. like scrolling.

I want if he is scrolling, at that point of time the text is so attractive that he won't be able to scroll down before reading the text. I know this is challenging to create such a user experience.